# Ignoring inverted bar (\) from db

Tags: php, laravel, escaping, laravel-blade

My db is returning a string like: `App\Model\Product`

So, when I get the data in order to put in my blade view it is ignoring the inverted bar `\`, print like this: `AppModelProduct`,

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Add more context. What you did that the DB returns a string. Show some code.

Comment: Using `{{ 'App\Model\Product' }}` in a template prints out `App\Model\Product` for me. You may post some code for the context and your exact Laravel version.

Answer (score 0):

Change your syntax from `{{ $yourVariable }}` to `{!! $yourVariable !!}`

Comment: Whenever you give somebody the advice to do something that might be a security risk please inform them of this fact! Your "answer" will echo unsafe variables which might make you vulnerable to XSS or other attacks! See [blade documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data) while paying special attention to the Displaying Unescaped Data section.

Comment: Noted the suggestion :) !!